# Twitter Search API and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-twitter

I need to use Twitter Search API and get twitter data into my HDFS. The Search API uses REST calls and I am trying to understand how I would use that with Apache Flume. I have required keys for authorization to use Twitter's APIs but I just don't understand how I could implement the Search API using flume. Need Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. create a developer account in twitter and generate your own secret keys.
2. Add a [flume-source-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](http://files.cloudera.com/samples/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) file into lib folder.
3. using secret keys create a flume config file to get tweets from twitter and store it into hdfs.
4. start you flume using below command

command : `bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent`

For more details refer the below link :

http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create application in twitter. Go to 
https://apps.twitter.com/ and create application then remember the generated four keys- Consumer key, Consumer Secret key, Access Token and Access Token Secret.

Download `apache-flume-1.x.0-bin.tar.gz`.here x means latest version.After untar the file add following command into `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export FLUME_HOME=location of untar flume file
export PATH=$PATH:$FLUME_HOME/bin
```

after saving the above file run `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal.After this follow below site command:

[https://acadgild.com/blog/streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/](http://acadgild.com/blog/streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/)